# Passing function from props to outside of the component (High Order Component)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to pass the function from high order component outside the class because I need to call it but it is also needed to be pass back. Hard to explain, here's the code:

**Wrapped Component:**

```
class foo extends React.Component {
    ....
}

foo.list = [
   {
      name: "Home",
      action: this.props.funcFromHoc //this.props.from foo class, how can i access this because it is outside the component?
   }
]

export default bar(foo);
```

**High Order Component:**

```
export default function bar(WrappedComponent) {

   funcFromHoc() {
      alert("Hello from HOC function!");
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <WrappedComponent 
            { ...this.props }
            funcFromHoc={ this.funcFromHoc }
      );
   }
}
```

**What I'm actually doing:**
I have a `base screen (HOC)` with a `2 drawers`, that has some functions that controls their behavior. I need this 2 drawers on `many screens` that I'll make, I don't want to put the configuration of the drawer for every screens, that's why I create a HOC for this. My problem is, the `list` on the drawer on HOC is `dynamic` on each screens, and they have `specific function` that I set on each screens, how can I pass a `function` from the `screen component` to HOC?

Am I missing something or this? Am I doing it wrong? Did I missed some of the proper usage of High Order Components? Or what method should I use for this? Any hint or help will be very much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: that looks like it should work.  are you using the HOC in unshown code in class foo like `export default bar(foo);` ?

Comment: I've update my code, yes sir please check below foo component

Comment: maybe you can update the foo code as well?  all this should be happening in a foo class function, I'm not really sure what the foo.list code is doing...  You should be able to access funcFromHoc in for example render like this: `render() { const { funcFromHoc } = this.props; // do something with funcFromHoc }`

Comment: Yes sir I can access the funcFromHoc INSIDE the foo class, but I want to pass it to the HOC as the action when the "Home" is clicked. The list is being propagated on the HOC. Or is there a way to access a variable INSIDE the class from the HOC? Like, WrappedComponent.list something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution, it solves my problem using **Inheritance Inversion**.

```
class foo extends React.Component {
   list() {
     return [
        {
           name: "Home",
           action: this.funcFromHoc //successfully accessed it here!
        }
     ];
   }
}

export default bar(foo);
```

**(High Order Component):**

```
export default function bar(WrappedComponent) {
   return class Bar extends WrappedComponent {

      funcFromHoc() {
         alert("Hello from HOC function!");
      }

      render() {
         return (
            //call super.list() here to populate drawer list
            {super.render()}
         );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: This does look like the answer.  I was stuck thinking about props proxy HOC.

Comment: I've almost dig the entire google hahahaha and come across with Inheritance Inversion. I've modified and modified my question from google just to suggest different links and answers that could give hint to me haha.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to be able to pass additional parameters to the HOC.  You could pass a mapping function when you call the HOC, like the color variable below.  Note the HOC is defined slightly differently as well in order to take additional arguments.

edit: nevermind, you won't have access to funcFromFoo unless it is a prop of foo (i.e. defined in mapDispatchToProps).  heh- i tried.  may need to rethink the design so this isn't a requirement.

```
function doSomethingWithList(props) {
  const { actionName, funcFromHOC, funcFromFooProps } = props;
  if (actionName === 'Home') {
    funcFromHOC();
  } else {
    funcFromFooProps();
  }
}; 

const makeToggleable = (WrappedComponent, color) => {
  return class ToggleableComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = { toggled: false };
      this.toggleColor = this.toggleColor.bind(this);
    }

    toggleColor() {
      this.setState({ toggled: !this.state.toggled });
    }

    render() {
      const fontColor = this.state.toggled? color: 'black';
      return (
        <WrappedComponent { ...this.props }
          style={{color: fontColor}}
          onClick={this.toggleColor} />
      );
    }
  }
}

export default makeToggleable(BaseComponent, 'red');

const listItems = [ 'Home', 'Other' ]; 

export default bar(foo, listItems, doSomethingWithList);
```

pass listItems and doSomethingWithList for OP's question, modify HOC to call doSomethingWithList with props

example code from https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/03/02/higher-order-components-in-react/

Comment: My problem sir is how can I pass the function from the WrappedComponent to the HOC that came from props. How can I pass for example, bar(foo, foo.props.color), something like this. It is a variable from inside the component. For this example, you're passing a static 'red', while my problem is, i want to pass the variable 'color' defined INSIDE the foo component.

Comment: I've never been called 'sir' on StackOverflow, you are so polite!  You can't do exactly what you are asking to do.  Without seeing the full code there is probably a design issue.  However, I updated the example to pass an action Map.  In your HOC, you could have some logic that inspects the actionMap and calls the correct function, but note you are not passing the actual function just a string key to lookup the function.

Comment: hehe not comfortable just calling by names. Well it might work if I pass a key that will lookup for the function, but what if I want to pass a function that is not on the HOC? for example, I want to pass a function from the wrappedcomponent itself. It is not scalable and flexible. Ill update my question with thing im working at so you can see if there's a another solution for it. Thank you very much sir, just a give a minute to update it.

Comment: I've updated my answer sir, please tell me if there's a part that is confusing.

Comment: Hi sir, I've found a solution, i used inheritance inversion. Thanks by the way for your help sir. :)